# Memory Leakage when accessing, using pointer, elements from a struct received by argument

Tags: c++, c, pointers, memory, memory-leaks

**A little of context:** I have recently developed a generic function to update a display image based just on which parts of it have changed. For that I receive as parameter a known struct which members are arrays of chars (display lines) and I compare it to the currently displayed information in order to update just the necessary, improving the performance. It is an embedded system for arm cortex-m0 in case it matters.
Below is the code code snippet for the struct.

```
struct displayLines {
    char firstLine[13];
    char secondLine[13];
    char thirdLine[13];
    char fourthLine[13];
    char fivethLine[13];
    char sixthLine[13];
};
typedef struct displayLines st_displayLines;
```

Based on that struct I use a pointer, initialized with the first element address and operate with it to access the whole struct data (all lines). Below is the code snippet showing how I initialize the pointer.

```
void updateScreen(st_displayLines st_toDisplay)
{
    char *ptrtoUpdate  = st_toDisplay.firstLine;
    char *ptrDisplayed = st_currentlyDisplayed.firstLine;

    //Here is the update code which consumes the pointers.
}
```

After operating with the same pointer variable (using arithmetic over it) and consuming its data I just return from the function, without using calling **free** operation over the pointer variable. 

**The question finally is:**

Is this a memory leakage? Or the allocated memory for creating the pointers will be released once I'm outside the function scope?

If it is a leakage, would it hold 1 byte per each pointer variable of my memory every time I call this function? In a manner that (making numbers now) if I have just 10 bytes of memory available, on the 6th call of the function my program would crash?

Comment: What exactly do you expect to "leak", here? You appear to be operating under a misunderstanding that you must always `free` after using a pointer. This is incorrect. You must always `free` everything that was `malloc`ed, at some point. Nothing more, nothing less. I don't see any `malloc`ing going on in the shown code, so there's nothing to `free` here.

Comment: Your variable is a *local copy* of the struct. It has automatic storage duration. Your code is also bad because it is probably a needless copy.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik That's the point of asking a question... I was probably misunderstanding/missing something. Thanks for your comment, seem pretty obvious now.

Comment: kind of <O/T>, since speed seems to be a concern for you, you should probably pass a pointer to `st_displayLines` to `updateScreen`, like this: `void updateScreen(const st_displayLines* st_toDisplay);` As is, each time you call that function, a copy of the entire structure is made, which will take a little extra time. However, there's not enough code to know if that's really what you want/need. With a pointer, only the pointer is copied, which is less data than the overall struct.

Comment: @yano I am passing the struct as value, so indeed I loose time copying the whole memory to the argument. Thanks for the advice, I'll change to pass just a pointer for the first element of the struct.

Comment: Any particular reason you're using a struct instead of a 2D array for everything, i.e. `char st_toDisplay[6][13]`?  it would make it easier to index the rows and columns.

Comment: @dbush Well noticed, backward compatibility is the reason. One of the reasons for the pointer is for making easier the indexing part of it.

Answer (score 2):

Memory leaks happen when memory allocated with `malloc` no longer has a pointer pointing to it and the memory is not free'ed.  The code as you've shown it doesn't allocate memory, so there's no leak.

Simply using a pointer variable is no different from using an `int`.  The variable is in scope at the point it is declared and goes out of scope at the end of the enclosing compound statement.  So no need to free anything.